# GridLayout of Buttons auto aligns left, ignoring Grid lines

Tags: android, android-layout, grid-layout, android-gridlayout

I have a very straightforward grid of buttons to make a keyboard. In this, I want "A" to be halfway in the middle of "Q" and "Z", so instead of 10 columns, which is what I require, I have 20 columns with each key spanning 2 columns. Here is the xml code:

```
<GridLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/GridLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:columnCount="20"
    android:rowCount="4"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    >

    <Button
        android:onClick="keyPress"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:id="@+id/keyQ"
        android:text="Q"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
        />
    <Button
        android:onClick="keyPress"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:id="@+id/keyW"
        android:text="W"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
        />
    <Button
        android:onClick="keyPress"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:id="@+id/keyE"
        android:text="E"
        android:layout_column="4"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
        />
    <Button
        android:onClick="keyPress"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:id="@+id/keyR"
        android:text="R"
        android:layout_column="6"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
        />
    <Button
        android:onClick="keyPress"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:id="@+id/keyT"
        android:text="T"
        android:layout_column="8"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
        />
    <Button
        android:onClick="keyPress"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:id="@+id/keyY"
        android:text="Y"
        android:layout_column="10"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
        />
    <Button
        android:onClick="keyPress"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:id="@+id/keyU"
        android:text="U"
        android:layout_column="12"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
        />
    <Button
        android:onClick="keyPress"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:id="@+id/keyI"
        android:text="I"
        android:layout_column="14"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
        />
    <Button
        android:onClick="keyPress"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:id="@+id/keyO"
        android:text="O"
        android:layout_column="16"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
        />
    <Button
        android:onClick="keyPress"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:id="@+id/keyP"
        android:text="P"
        android:layout_column="18"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
        />

    <Button
        android:onClick="keyPress"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:id="@+id/keyA"
        android:text="A"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
        />
    <Button
        android:onClick="keyPress"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:id="@+id/keyS"
        android:text="S"
        android:layout_column="3"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
        />
    <Button
        android:onClick="keyPress"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:id="@+id/keyD"
        android:text="D"
        android:layout_column="5"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
        />
    <Button
        android:onClick="keyPress"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:id="@+id/keyF"
        android:text="F"
        android:layout_column="7"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
        />
    <Button
        android:onClick="keyPress"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:id="@+id/keyG"
        android:text="G"
        android:layout_column="9"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
        />
    <Button
        android:onClick="keyPress"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:id="@+id/keyH"
        android:text="H"
        android:layout_column="11"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
        />
    <Button
        android:onClick="keyPress"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:id="@+id/keyJ"
        android:text="J"
        android:layout_column="13"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
        />
    <Button
        android:onClick="keyPress"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:id="@+id/keyK"
        android:text="K"
        android:layout_column="15"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
        />
    <Button
        android:onClick="keyPress"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:id="@+id/keyL"
        android:text="L"
        android:layout_column="17"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
        />
    <Button
        android:onClick="keyPress"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:id="@+id/keyCaps"
        android:text=""
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
        />
    <Button
        android:onClick="keyPress"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:id="@+id/keyZ"
        android:text="Z"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
        />
    <Button
        android:onClick="keyPress"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:id="@+id/keyX"
        android:text="X"
        android:layout_column="4"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
        />
    <Button
        android:onClick="keyPress"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:id="@+id/keyC"
        android:text="C"
        android:layout_column="6"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
        />
    <Button
        android:onClick="keyPress"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:id="@+id/keyV"
        android:text="V"
        android:layout_column="8"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
        />
    <Button
        android:onClick="keyPress"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:id="@+id/keyB"
        android:text="B"
        android:layout_column="10"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
        />
    <Button
        android:onClick="keyPress"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:id="@+id/keyN"
        android:text="N"
        android:layout_column="12"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
        />
    <Button
        android:onClick="keyPress"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:id="@+id/keyM"
        android:text="M"
        android:layout_column="14"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
        />
    <Button
        android:onClick="keyPress"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:id="@+id/keyDelete"
        android:text="◀️"
        android:layout_column="16"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_columnSpan="4"
        />
    <Button
        android:onClick="keyPress"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:id="@+id/keyColon"
        android:text=":"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_row="3"
        android:layout_columnSpan="3"
        />
    <Button
        android:onClick="keyPress"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:id="@+id/keySpace"
        android:text=""
        android:layout_column="4"
        android:layout_row="3"
        android:layout_columnSpan="12"
        />
    <Button
        android:onClick="keyPress"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:id="@+id/keyPeriod"
        android:text="."
        android:layout_column="16"
        android:layout_row="3"
        android:layout_columnSpan="3"
        />

</GridLayout>
```

I want the keyboard to look normal (as described above) but the empty column seems to be ignored and the keyboard ends up looking like this:

[Picture of the result of the XML layout file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BrdKs.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put all them in one `viewgroup` and put some pillow in two side of them  :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/GridLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:columnCount="20"
    android:rowCount="4"

    >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/keyQ"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:onClick="keyPress"
        android:text="Q" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/keyW"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:onClick="keyPress"
        android:text="W" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/keyE"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="4"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:onClick="keyPress"
        android:text="E" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/keyR"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="6"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:onClick="keyPress"
        android:text="R" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/keyT"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="8"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:onClick="keyPress"
        android:text="T" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/keyY"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="10"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:onClick="keyPress"
        android:text="Y" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/keyU"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="12"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:onClick="keyPress"
        android:text="U" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/keyI"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="14"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:onClick="keyPress"
        android:text="I" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/keyO"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="16"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:onClick="keyPress"
        android:text="O" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/keyP"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="18"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:onClick="keyPress"
        android:text="P" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_row="1"

        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_columnSpan="19"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.4"
            android:visibility="invisible" />


        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.4"
            android:visibility="invisible" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/keyCaps"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:onClick="keyPress"
        android:text="" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/keyZ"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:onClick="keyPress"
        android:text="Z" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/keyX"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_column="4"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:onClick="keyPress"
        android:text="X" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/keyC"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_column="6"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:onClick="keyPress"
        android:text="C" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/keyV"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_column="8"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:onClick="keyPress"
        android:text="V" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/keyB"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_column="10"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:onClick="keyPress"
        android:text="B" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/keyN"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_column="12"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:onClick="keyPress"
        android:text="N" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/keyM"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_column="14"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:onClick="keyPress"
        android:text="M" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/keyDelete"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_column="16"
        android:layout_columnSpan="4"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:onClick="keyPress"
        android:text="◀️" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/keyColon"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_row="3"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_columnSpan="3"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:onClick="keyPress"
        android:text=":" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/keySpace"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_row="3"
        android:layout_column="4"
        android:layout_columnSpan="12"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:onClick="keyPress"
        android:text="" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/keyPeriod"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_row="3"
        android:layout_column="16"
        android:layout_columnSpan="3"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:onClick="keyPress"
        android:text="." />

</GridLayout>
```

Comment: That is a solution, but would that not change for different display sizes? And the row would never be centered, it would always tilt a particular way.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH. I should have gone to Stack Overflow earlier. I spent my whole day and you noble soul saved me another wonderful day from being ruined. THANKS!